# Disable focus function in an existing script with greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

A follow up on one of my earlier questions;

My goal was to make a script that auto clicks a button to display a quick reply box on a forum, which I've succeeded in doing. However, the issue right now is that on each page load, it goes straight to the bottom where the quick reply is as the text field is indeed focused.

What would I need to write in greasemonkey to stop it from moving all the way down to the textfield? I'm guessing I'd have to disable the 'message' focus section, but I'm unsure how to go about that.

The script below is the one generated on the site at hand, and not the script I've been writing.

```
function hide_qr(show)
{
dE('qr_editor_div');
dE('qr_showeditor_div');
if (show && document.getElementById('qr_editor_div').style.display != 'none')
{
document.getElementsByName('message')[0].focus();
}
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the element is only focused if this condition is true:

```
if (show && document.getElementById('qr_editor_div').style.display != 'none') {
  document.getElementsByName('message')[0].focus();
}
```

If `show` is `false`, the element doesn't get focused. `show` is also the only argument for this function, so if you set it to `false`, the element doesn't focus.

Therefore, try running the function using `hide_qr(false)` instead of `hide_qr(true)`.

Comment: Oh god, how could I have missed that? You're absolutely right and it worked. Thanks a bunch Blender.

Comment: No problem! [filling 15 characters]